# Replacing the WHERE with LEFT JOIN or something else clever

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM
table1,
table2,
table3,
table4,
table5,
table6,
table7,
table8
WHERE
a = b and
c = d and
e = d and
x1 = g and /*this is where x1 is changed into x2,x3,x4 or x5, labor intensive stuff*/ 
f = h and
i = j
```

The problem is that some j's only work with some x1 to x5 and and so on, it depends on a variable in a field called strfldvar. All I know is that the query works for **x1 = g** only when **strfldvar = 'str1'** and **x2 = g** only when **strfldvar = 'str2'** and so on, so I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM
table1,
table2,
table3,
table4,
table5,
table6,
table7,
table8
WHERE
a = b and
c = d and
e = d and
(
(strfldvar = 'str1' AND x1 = g) 
OR (strfldvar = 'str2' AND x2 = g)
OR (strfldvar = 'str3' AND x3 = g)
OR (strfldvar = 'str4' AND x4 = g)
OR (strfldvar = 'str5' AND x5 = g)
)    and
f = h and
i = j
```

This takes forever to run and is stopped by **time out on query**. I guess that there is a cartesian product behind that makes this so complex and time consuming so there is obviously **something wrong with the query**. I have also tried to use CASE THEN to turn off all the '=' that are irrelavant after the WHERE and that gives the same results.
Can I change my query by implementing JOIN, LEFT JOIN, OUTER JOIN, INNER JOIN, UNION or something else to **make this work fast for all cases of strfldvar** or is there no simple answer to this? The specific information for each type of strfldvar are connected to table4 to table8, additional info for str1 type of records are kept in table4 and the same for table8 and str5 and all between.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: . . If you want to fix this problem, start by rewriting the query to place table aliases in front of all columns and use proper ANSI join syntax.  You might also explain which tables have which indexes.

Comment: Please indent the code properly so that it is easier to read. Also, placing everything onto its own line makes the query verbose and very spread out.

Comment: To go more in depth on what Gordon has said, I'd recommend reading [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) in the bad habits to kick series by [Aaron Bertrand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand), the articles are targeted at SQL-Server, but many apply to all DBMS. It is worth considering though, that Oracle *can* on some occassions produce better plans when using ANSI 89 JOIN syntax (implicit) compared to ANSI 92 explicit join syntax.

Comment: thanks for your comments Gordon, usr, GarethD .. I guess there is no simple answer and I have to dig into this and change my question or answer it myself if lucky.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Inner join instead of running the scanning through whole table. Actually, in your case, you are selecting the data from the 8 table then running the scanning through whole data, which is really not a good technique. Instead you should use the Inner joins which will scan your results on sequence basics and make your query comparatively fast. Your code will look like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 Inner join table2 On table1.a=table2.b
                    Inner join table3 On table2.b=table2.c
```

and so on..

Comment: You really underestimate the Oracle optimizer.  The original query should run the same as the equivalent version with inner joins.  SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  You describe what the output should look like, and the optimizer can choose different ways to achieve that goal.

Comment: While I agree that for the most part people should be using `ANSI 92 Join syntax` is a good idea, your reasoning is not true at all. 
`SELECT * FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id` will generate the [exact same execution plan](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f336b/1) as `SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON b.ID = a.ID`, it
will not as you assume scan all tables before reaching the where clause.